# How to filter out an iframe from feed

Tags: feed, iframe

There is some iframe inside post content and I want to get rid of that iframe when the rss feeds are generated. To generate rss feeds, I'm showing full post content.

I started looking at `strip_tags()` but it does pretty much the opposite: strip everything unless the desired tags.

I'm wondering that maybe there is some hook and some wordpress-y form of solving this issue.

I know I should do something like this:

```
function rss_noiframe($content) {
    global $post;
    // filter out iframe here
    return $content;
    }

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'rss_noiframe');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'rss_noiframe');
```

But I'm lost at this point. Any ideas?

[On demand by EAmann](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81858/how-to-filter-out-an-iframe-from-feed/81868#comment110495_81868), here is some example code that isnt modified at all (it still appears in the feed, in fact):

```
<iframe src="http://somedomain.net/path/to/frame" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="500" height="375"></iframe>
```

Comment: What is adding the iframe? Is it a plugin, a shortcode, manually entered in the HTML editor?

Comment: Manually entered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential option is to use `preg_replace` to do a regex match on your content and replace the iframe with empty space.

So this function:

```
function rss_noiframe($content) {
    $content = preg_replace( '/<iframe(.*)\/iframe>/is', '', $content );

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'rss_noiframe');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'rss_noiframe');
```

Should automatically convert any instances of `<iframe src=...>...</iframe>` to a blank.

Comment: thanks, i will try this :) i'm not that skilled with regex and couldnt come up with a solution myself :)

Comment: It didnt work, it leaves a completely cleared rss :S

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include some example HTML that has the iframe?  All of my tests of the above code worked just fine ...

Comment: Ok, sorry, it was my fault... Your code works indeed! I was calling the_content() to do further processing (add thumbnail) and that was overriding your regex.

Comment: I have the same issue but can't solve it. Please where do I place this function for it to be effective